# Does this recurent matrix sequence admit an explicit writing?

Tags: matrices, sequences-and-series, matrix-equations

I have sequence defined by : (n+1)=(−(Ф.(n).Ф′+).′.(.(Ф.(n).Ф′+).′+)^(−).).(Ф.(n).Ф′ +)

Where :

- P(n), Q, R are square, NxN, symmetric, positive semidefinite.
- R is square, MxM, symmetric, positive semidefinite.
- Ф is square, NxN
- H is MxN

I can't figure out any explicit form without adding any assumption of commutativity. Any idea ?